# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python writer.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Explain, please.
I have at the moment:
Python 3.8.2
ubuntu 20.
vscode

relative ./

files are located in this path
./writer.py
reader.py
I have files here
I run this code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


p1 = Popen('python writer.py', stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen('python reader.py', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

I get this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

I tried the full path anyway, this error changed to `'python3 ./riter.py'` or `python3 /home/path.../writer.py` all the same.

but if you try like this,

```
import os


p1 = os.popen('python3 ./writer.py', 'r')
p2 = os.popen('python3 ./read.py', 'w')
print(p2.write(p1.read()))
```

then it works. But that's another topic

Comment: A quick check. Verify whether `python` command is working or not. Seems like python3 is working and `python` isn't. Go to terminal and enter python. It will most likely give you an error.

Comment: you see, i checked both python3 and python. alas, doesn't work